# Почему в 2D играх используют раскадровку, а не GIF анимацию?

Tags: разработка-игр, анимация, спрайт

Решил для самообразования создать простенькую 2D игру. Встал вопрос: 
почему люди используют раскадровки, а не готовые GIF?

Comment: я могу ее сделать в фотошопе. и вывести готовый гиф. поэтому и спрашиваю) вдруг кто знает.)
я хочу использовать\рисовать в фотошопе

Comment: Если умеешь английский, то вот хороший ответ: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130580/why-dont-most-major-game-engines-use-gifs-for-animated-textures/130609#130609

Comment: А как ты в гиф будешь регулировать скорость анимации, к примеру? В какой-то момент ты решил что мигалка слишком быстро крутится. Что - пересобирать гиф?))  а если персонаж должен то быстро то медленно двигаться?  а если персонаж делает серию ударов (комбо), то нарезать всевозмжные комбинации гифок?) К тому же, куда помещать эти гифки? в игре происходит процесс перерисовки сцены. около 60 раз в секунду.... где именно должна располагаться гифка, чтоб начинать анимацию с того же момента, с которого была прервана после обновления рендеринга сцены?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо)

Comment: @Kromster спасибо)

Comment: @Kromster мы ждем тут перевода ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ответы в ответы?

Comment: @Qwertiy ответы в ответах!

Answer (score 17):

Недостатки *GIF*:

- очень ограниченная цветовая палитра: обычно это 256 цветов с плохим сглаживанием. (да, [можно использовать и больше 256 цветов](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/304/can-i-have-an-animated-gif-with-more-than-256-colours-per-frame), но это очень редкие случаи)
- графические процессоры (GPU) не поддерживают сжатие (компрессию) *GIF*, а это значит, что так или иначе её придется распаковывать и при этом уже за счет центрального процессора (CPU)
- для прозрачности вы можете использовать только ОДИН цвет (если только не выполняете свою индивидуальную обработку)
- нет произвольного доступа: для доступа к нужному кадру *GIF* - необходимо произвести чтение и декомпрессию предыдущих
- вам нужно иметь в коде специальную функцию для декомпрессии. Вы не сможете выбрать другие (лучшие) алгоритмы сжатия (да, [несжатые *GIF* тоже существуют](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Uncompressed_GIF), но это довольно редкие случаи)
- не поддерживает векторную графику.

Когда вы работаете со своим форматом, то все вопросы решаются быстро. У вас больше контроля над форматом изображения, качеством, прозрачности,  произвольным доступом и сжатием
(включая DXT, которые поддерживают GPU). Кроме того вы можете определить приоритеты нужных вам функций.

Некоторые думают, что у *GIF* есть преимущество относительно спрайт-листов, якобы не нужно переживать, что кадр будет идти слишком быстро или слишком медленно и пытаться выправить скорость в коде.
Но это не так. Синхронизация частоты кадров *GIF* анимации и синхронизация с анимацией спрайт-листов не сильно отличается. 
В обоих случаях придется знать и манипулировать списком кадров, устанавливать желаемую частоту кадров и работать с событиями рендеринга (отрисовки). *GIF* - не создаст магии, для достижения цели
вам в любом случае придется распаковывать *GIF* в спрайт-лист.

Пожалуй единственное место, где не нужно переживать за кадры - *HTML / CSS GUI*, но и они сейчас применяются там довольно редко...ну и ресурсоёмкие они

+

Как я писал в комментарии, более простым языком: есть у тебя *GIF*-анимация мигалок на полицейской и пожарной машине. В какой-то момент ты решил, что мигалки слишком быстро крутятся...Пересобирать *GIF*? Не вариант. А если опять не понравилось?

А если  персонаж должен двигаться то быстро, то медленно (например slow mo). А если персонаж делает серию ударов (комбо), причем остановится может на любой из серии ударов, а также каждая анимация
у прерванной комбинации своя (пример комбинации: UMK3 ultimate - Liu Kang - 4-ре удара ногами. Анимация возврата ноги - разная). Вопрос:  нарезать всевозможные комбинации *GIF*?

К тому же, где должен происходить процесс воспроизведения гиф-анимации? В игре происходит процесс перерисовки сцены. Около 60 раз в секунду (плюс/минус). 
Где именно должна располагаться *GIF*, чтоб начинать анимацию с того же момента, с которого была прервана после обновления рендеринга сцены? Или как должна синхронизироваться? Всё это выливается в большую головную боль.

---

<sub>небольшой переводик с отсебятиной [gamedevSE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/130609/81175)</sub>

Answer (score 10):

Вопрос некорректен. Не существует взаимоисключающих методов "раскадаровка" и "GIF-анимация". Нет никакого "а не". Это ортогональные понятия. Правильно вопрос поставить так:

### Почему в 2D играх не хранят раскадровку в формате GIF?

Когда вы находитесь в игре, вы работаете с битами и байтами графики, которые находятся в "аппаратном" состоянии. Обычно это либо несжатая графика (вариация ARGB, например), либо сжатая поддерживаемым аппаратно (то есть видеокартой) алгоритмом (вариация DXT, например).

**Раскадровка** — это несколько изображений (обычно кадров анимации), которые могут как находиться на одной текстуре (одной "плоскости" байтов), так и на нескольких. Расположение графики на одной текстуре необязательно, но имеет некоторые преимущества, например, более рациональное впихивание в аппаратно оптимальные размеры текстуры.

**GIF** — это формат хранения данных на диске. Условно он содержит кадры и задержки между ними, но вообще-то это мудрёный формат с построчным хранением данных и разнообразными алгоритмами перехода между кадрами (например, "откатить состояние до предыдущего кадра, наложить следующий с прозрачностью и другой палитрой"). Этот формат не имеет ничего общего с тем, как данные отображаются в современных компьютерах на современном железе.

Иногда создаётся впечатление, что GIF "просто работает". Это не так. Внутри программ находятся компоненты, которые извлекают кадры в аппаратный вид и согласно алгоритмам выводят их на экран по таймеру.

Когда вы пишете игру, вы всем управляете сами. У вас больше нет разрознённых "анимаций", у вас есть чёткое состояние каждого объекта вместе со всеми кадрами всех элементов в каждый отдельный момент времени, в каждый кадр. У вас полный контроль над тем, какой кадр анимации отображается при начале прыжка после бега.

Теперь по сути: **GIF-анимация *может* использоваться для раскадровки, но это редко делается из-за ужасающих ограничений формата GIF**, которые перечислены в другом ответе.

В современном мире обычно используются форматы, которые хранят графику прямо в аппаратном виде. Это позволяет делать загрузку очень быстрой, но требует довольно много памяти, потому что сжатие слабое. Некоторые игры могут идти альтернативным путём, например, Braid хранит графику в JPEG, причём канал прозрачности в отдельном файле. Если вы хотите оптимизировать место на диске, поджертвовав временем загрузки, и ваша графика лучше всего сжимается GIF, причём без потерь, то **использование GIF для хранения кадров анимации *может* быть рациональным**.

Отдельно надо отметить движки на базе **HTML**. Там GIF действительно работает "из коробки". Однако даже там продолжают действовать ограничения GIF: как ограничение формата в виде ограниченной палитры, так и ограничения в контроле над потрохами в виде отсутствия контроля над текущим кадром и так далее. Даже в HTML использовать GIF имеет смысл в очень ограниченных случаях: если изображение идеально ложится в ограничения формата, а точный контроль не нужен. Это случается редко, в сложных играх — никогда.

Answer (score 0):

Так именно потому, что gif **готовая**. Ну анимируешь ты прыжки мячика и исчезновение ящиков, в которые он попал. Дальше что? Игра-то где? А нет её. Смысл игры как раз в том, что сам игрок отбил мячик в определённом направлении или вообще уронил его. И надо **после этого** отрисовать его движение.